# How can I include a remote private git file in .gitlab-cy.yml?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want that my `.gitlab-ci.yml` starts with:

```
include:
- remote: https://gitlab-ci-token:$GL_TOKEN@gitlab.com/..../template/-/raw/master/glab-ci-template.yml
```

The idea is to import a template to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. However, I receive a 403 ERROR.

How can I import the template file fro another private repository, that I have access?
Thanks

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includeremote) authentication schemas in the remote URL are not supported